# How many lags of independent variables to use

Tags: model-selection, lags, multinomial-logit

I have a panel dataset (26880 observations) of individual decisions ($y_{it}$, a categorical variable) which depends on signals ($x_{it}$). I am trying to find out how many past signals individuals are taking into account when making decisions. Importantly, I have three treatments, which in principle should affect how many signals subjects are using, and I am testing it.

In the multinomial logit regressions, I am using interaction terms of treatment and $x_{it}$ and its lags.

I am planning to add lags of $x_{it}$ until the last lag has no significant effect on the marginal effect. When I add 0-3 lags, the results are as expected, but the last lag still has a significant effect, so I am adding 4 lags. The results turn out to be inconsistent in the way that in the treatment where only $x_{it}$ is significant before, now the $x_{it-4}$ is also significant. If I add more lags, the last lag in the treatment is significant.

Could it because more lags cause multicollinearity so that I am getting inconsistent results?

I also have looked at the log likelihood and information criteria, it turns out the specification with more lags has larger likelihood and lower IC, and so is more favourable. However, I am in doubt of the results with say 5, or 6 lags, because in the study design, individuals only have access to $x_{it}$, and if past signals have any effect, individuals have to memorise them, and I don't think they would memorise so many past signals.

Is there another principle that I should follow when deciding how many lags of an independent variable to add in a regression?

Comment: Could you please add a plot of the crosscovariance $f(\tau)=E[(y(t)-E[y(t)])(x(t+\tau)-E[x(t+\tau)])]$, averaging over all t ?

Comment: @Ggjj11, the dependent variable is a multi-response categorical variable, and independent variable is continuous, I am not sure how to get the covariance between the two, could you please elaborate a bit more?